# AngularJS directive not injecting & giving error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to inject a `directive`, but I am getting some error. Actually, I have declared the `modules` as the array, and pushing to the app, but still not working.

here is my code :

```
var appModules = ['app.directives', []]

var app = angular.module('plunker', appModules);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});


angular.module('app.directives', []).directive('myContent', function(){

  return{

    link:function(scope, element, attrs){

      console.log("hi");

    }

  }

})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZwMxeeO5v11arAfHh78?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `var appModules = ['app.directives', []]` to `var appModules = ['app.directives']`

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of a module declaration is an array of the dependencies. but you have an extra empty array in the appmodules that you are passing to injection

Change

```
var appModules = ['app.directives', []]
```

to

```
var appModules = ['app.directives']
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kmjgGwUzvv1sWc2Nyetj?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: I agree, Is it common all event all ( including `controllers`)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking...or if that is even a question

Answer (score 1):

In `appModules` you cannot use blank array inside it.

Since It will not recognize the modules, inside that because an empty array exist there.

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', ['app.directives', []]);
```

when we inject `appModules` directly, then it obviously give an error

> Failed to instantiate module

because it does not recognize the empty array inside it.

```
 var appModules = ['app.directives'];
```

This is , what you have to use.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code in the following way:

```
// Define the name of the directive module
var directiveModule = 'app.directives';

// Create the directive module itself
angular.module('app.directives', []);

var appModules = [directiveModule];

// Create the main module
var app = angular.module('plunker', appModules);

// Add controller on the main module
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
});

// Register directive on the directives module
angular.module('app.directives').directive('myContent', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("hi");
        }
    }
});
```

Remember: `angular.module('some-name', [])` create a new module with name `some-name` while `angular.module('some-name')` will use an existing module with name `some-name` and will throw exception if that module is not created before.